# Moving Options with Python and TKinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am brand new to coding as my company is paying for me to get some technical schooling.  I have ran into a problem with attempting to control the speed of an object with the arrow keys in a Python TKinter project.  Could anyone take a look at the following code below, please?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
 width = 1000
 height = 200
 radius = 20

 from tkinter import *

 class main():
     def __init__(self):
         window = Tk()
         window.title("Car")

         self.canvas = Canvas(window, bg = "white", width = width, height = height)
         self.canvas.pack()

#build car and speed control

         self.canvas.create_rectangle(10,100,210, 125, fill = "red", tags = "rect")
         self.canvas.create_rectangle(150, 50, 200, 100, fill = "blue", tags = "rect")
         self.canvas.create_oval(40 - radius, 200 - radius, 60 + radius, 100 + radius, fill = "black", tags = "oval")
         self.canvas.create_oval(160 - radius, 200 - radius, 180 + radius, 100 + radius, fill = "black", tags = "oval")
         self.canvas.bind('<Up>', self.up)
         self.canvas.bind('<Down>', self.down)
         self.canvas.focus_set()

    # start movement

         dx = 5
         x = 0
         while True:
             self.canvas.move("rect", dx, 0)
             self.canvas.after(100)
             self.canvas.update()
             self.canvas.move("oval", dx, 0)
             self.canvas.after(100)
             self.canvas.update()
             if x < width - 210:   #Test for end of screen
                 x += dx
             else:                  # delete and start animation again
                 x = 0
                 self.canvas.delete("rect")
                 self.canvas.delete("oval")
                 self.canvas.create_rectangle(10,100,210, 125, fill = "red", tags = "rect")
                 self.canvas.create_rectangle(150, 50, 200, 100, fill = "blue", tags = "rect")
                 self.canvas.create_oval(40 - radius, 200 - radius, 60 + radius, 100 + radius, fill = "black", tags = "oval")
                 self.canvas.create_oval(160 - radius, 200 - radius, 180 + radius, 100 + radius, fill = "black", tags = "oval")


         window.mainloop()


# define speed control functions

     def up(self,event):
         dx += 5

     def down(self,event):
         dx -= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

So far you've only defined your class, `main()`. You need to create an instance of that class below the class definition in order for your window to appear. For example, you could initialize an instance called `game` with

```
game = main()
```

And when you run that code, you should see your window pop up.

You'll also see that the truck just moves to the right regardless of whether you press the `<Up>` or `<Down>` keys that you bound functions to. If you have a debugger, you may see it producing an `UnboundLocalError` with the message:

```
local variable 'dx' referenced before assignment
```

This error shows up because dx has only been defined in the scope of `main()`. If you want to make `dx` accessible within the entire class, change every `dx` to `self.dx`.

If you run your program again, you should see that you can control the speed of the car with the `<Up>` and `<Down>` keys.

If you're having problems or want to add any features, let me know.

-Jason

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am going to start playing around with the advice that you gave.  Your a life saver!